# How do I find a MongoDB document with a field that matches a field in a document in another collection?

Tags: mongodb

I have one collection with documents that have a "host" field, and I'm trying to match it to a document in a very large collection that has the same host.  Both collections are on the order of a million documents.  I'm still figuring out Mongo, but I believe I can do it crudely, iterating with Javascript.  Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Just remember define index for theme, with indices the query perform so quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RDBMS, that would be a JOIN, something which doesn't exist on planet Mongo.

It really depends on your use case and your data model. The difference in data modeling between RDBMS and NoSQL databases is that you do data modelling for the former by the question "What answers can be provided by the data I have?" whereas data modeling for the latter is done by the question "Which questions do I have to be answered by the data?"

If you have a given host, the question is easy: "Which hosts in collection B match the given host I have?" Let's assume you have linked the documents via the `_id` field. Then you would simply do

```
db.B.find({fieldToMatch:<givenHostsIdValue>})
```

e.g.

```
db.B.find({runningOnHost:e67848a7282919ac})
```

In case you have to correlate all hosts to the second table, you might (and most likely will) have to denormalize your data by embedding the host data into your other table. For example, when you try to keep track of all services that have to run on any given host, your modelling could look like this:

```
{
  _id:e67848a7282919ac,
  processes:['httpd', 'mongod', 'varnish'],
  running:[’httpd’,’varnish’]
  host: {
    hostname: "web1.emea.mycompany.com",
    ip:10.0.0.1,
    datacenter: "EMEA"
  }
 }
```

This would describe ("document") a host in full, and you could do several interesting questions on this collection:

```
db.hosts.find({processes:'httpd','host.datacenter':'us-east'})
```

to find all designated web servers in the us-east datacenter or

```
db.hosts.find({'host.hostname':/emea.mycompany.com/},{host:1,processes:1,running:1})
```

to get the running processes and the ones which are supposed to run for all hosts of the domain `emea.mycompany.com`. Using the aggregation framework, you could even do extremely complex queries on that collection.

Please have a deep look into the docs about a [Data Modeling](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/) and the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/). Combined, they should make it possible to answer the questions you have on your data. ;)

Comment: Yep, that's what I thought as well, knowing denormalization is a NoSQL mantra.  It can be difficult when the needs of the software's operation are different than the needs of the debuggers/researchers.  Do we double the size of the database for the purpose of the occasional investigation?

Comment: That depends. Actually you wouldn't copy the data, but store it in a different location. That usually doesn't double the size. ;)

Comment: Aha! So Mongo has some intelligence behind the scenes to manage that.  Looking forward to getting more edumacated on this.